# Check my work on a problem involving Law of Cosines?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

The problem is this:

Jane walks North for 3 miles, then turns $45^\circ$ to the right. After that, she walks another 4 miles.

How many miles will Jane be from her starting point? Give your answer as a decimal rounded to the nearest hundredth.

When writing this problem, I had point B be where Jane started, Point A the point where she made the $45^\circ$ turn to the right, and Point C the point where she was finished in the triangle ABC.

I then applied the Law of Cosines:

$a^2 = b^2+c^2-2bc*\cos(A)$, where $a$ denotes the side that I am supposed to find. Plugging the different values in, where $b = 4, c = 3,$ and $A = 45^\circ$, I ended up getting $a = \sqrt{25-12\sqrt{2}}$, which gives me $2.83$. However, that was incorrect. Did I make a small mistake anywhere? I've redone this problem five times and cannot seem to find my mistake.

Comment: The included angle to use in the Law of Cosines for this triangle is 135º , rather than 45º ; that is what a "turn of 45º" from the original direction of travel produces between the "legs" of the path.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: Ah, I see. I thought that may have been the case, but I wasn't sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the diagram below, the $45^\circ$ angle described in the problem is an exterior angle of the triangle you must use to solve the problem.  The angle you want to use, as RecklessReckoner pointed out, is the $135^\circ$ angle supplementary to that angle.[image]

Applying the Law of Cosines to the triangle shown in the diagram yields

$$a^2 = (3~\text{miles})^2 + (4~\text{miles})^2 - 2(3~\text{miles})(4~\text{miles})\cos(135^\circ)$$

Drawing a diagram is a useful step in solving problems that use the Law of Sines or Law of Cosines.